# rails-admin get_collection from querystring params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm doing the following with rails-admin:

```
config.actions do
    collection :message do
      only ['User']
      http_methods { [:post, :get] }

      controller do
        proc do
          if request.get?
          elsif request.post?
            users = self.get_collection(@model_config, nil, nil)
          end
        end
      end
    end
end
```

The problem is that `@model_config` is not making use of the query string params and `get_collection` is returning the whole list of users. Is there a way to get the collection, filtering by the query string params? 
(I am passing those exactly as the view is getting them in the get method - in which they are working)

Comment: ok, can you tell what you see if you do `raise params[:query].inspect` inside the controller?

Comment: @ArupRakshit how's it going? :-) I was misconstructing the params. I got that figured out =)

Comment: Anyway, so saw https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/controllers/rails_admin/main_controller.rb#L128 and thought to ask you do check if the `params` is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

My bad -

I was misconstructing the params. Here's a good way of making sure things are being passed correctly so the code above would work.

```
= form_tag message_path(request.query_parameters), method: 'post' do |f|
```